# Google Streetview: Show markers within given radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have added custom markers to google maps streetview view without a problem. I am now wanting to show the markers I have added only when the user is within a few degrees of the markers coordinates and not visible when panning around street view from farther distances. I have seen a few forum posts about removing markers when in a given radius but not the reverse.

Litte more background... I am trying to make a simple easter egg hunt game using the streetview api.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks @geocodezip I will give it a try and repost my results.

Comment: I completed this project a while ago and never posted anything more about it. If you are interested checkout http://dayinpompeii.com to see the completed project.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I have seen a few forum posts about removing markers when in a given radius but not the reverse", use that mechanism and reverse the test.